# Where can i put my db query data and hold that to use after loading a view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mysqli

I am working with model view controller that is developed by me for my website in PHP.

This is how my mvc works:

1. User puts his log in credentials and request goes to router.
2. Router decides which controller to load and in my case its authController.
3. Controller checks the request and loads a respective model for this.
4. The model checks the username and password while querying mysqli db.
5. On success, model returns to the same controller with success status.
6. The controller then loads the respective VIEW. In my case it is profile page.

In 4th point, i want to put my query data somewhere so that i can easily access that data inside my view. I mean i can use the username for displaying on the top of the view profile page. I know some people hold there data inside sessions but sessions are super global. I need a suggestion. Thanks

This is the link i got most of the help from [Model View Controller](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

Comment: Why not let your view request the success status from the model?  If it checks out you can have your view load the profile page, otherwise have it print out an error to the user.

Comment: is it a good practice to let the view interact with the model rather with controller. In my MVC, model gives the status to the controller in case of success or fail and then controller loads the respective view for this.

Comment: I think the _model_ should be the "heart" of things. Controller and View should interact with it and not with each other, unlike the loose concept some MVC frameworks allow. Controller should interact with Model and decide (with model's help) what view should be served, which in turn communicates with Model for its own parametrization.

Comment: In my point of view, the application would be more secure if there is only one gateway to get the information. In my framework, i have added some extra layers. Request cannot directly go to the controller. Its the Router's job to select the particular controller for this and then controllers deals interacts with models and views. I think my model should return data to the controller and the while loading a view the data should also be passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CodeIgniter style ?

where you can load `$this->load->view(your_view, $username);` in your controller

Comment: Man you gave me a clue to handle this. I should return the data to the controller from the model and then load the respective view for this and pass the data to the view as argument. Actually this framework is designed by me and it was my first try ever. Thanks by the way.

Comment: -1: why not use codeigniter style: because it is one of the most horrible frameworks in PHP and has **nothing** to do with MVC.